# Convert multiple columns in pandas dataframe into a timestamp - rounded to nearest 15 minute interval

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 3 columns in a dataframe date, hour and minute

```
         date  hour  minute
0  2018-01-01     0      10
1  2018-01-01     1      20
2  2018-01-01     2      50
3  2018-01-01     3      40
4  2018-01-01     4       7
5  2018-01-01     5       0
6  2018-01-01     6       2
```

I need to combine these columns into 1 timestamp column, but the timestamp should be rounded to the nearest 15 minute interval.

So myexpected output would be

```
timestamp
2018-01-01 00:15
2018-01-01 01:15
2018-01-01 02:45
2018-01-01 03:45
2018-01-01 04:00
2018-01-01 05:00
2018-01-01 06:00
```

Comment: rounded to the nearest.... either up or down. whichever quarter hour interval is closest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use:

```
(pd.to_datetime(df['date']) +
 pd.to_timedelta(df['hour'], 'H') +
 pd.to_timedelta(df['minute'], 'm')).dt.round('15min')
```